# Why debug pointer moves to first line of source method instead of moving to first line of a method where the debug pointer is currently present?

Tags: java

Under what circumstances does the below happens in Eclipse Debugger?

Class 1:

```
public class Sample {
    public static void sourceMethod(BeanClass bean, Map<String, List<String>> hmMap){
        try {
            System.out.println();
            enterData(bean, hmMap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public static void enterData(BeanClass bean, Map<String, List<String>> hmMap){
        try {
            System.out.println("hello");//Comment or Uncomment this line while debugging 
            System.out.println("Value : "+hmMap.get("KeyValue").get(0));
            bean.setResult(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            bean.setResult(false);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        BeanClass bean = new BeanClass();
        Map<String, List<String>> hmMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("hi");
        list.add("hello");
        hmMap.put("KeyValue", list);
        Sample.sourceMethod(bean, hmMap);
    }
}
```

Class 2:

```
public class BeanClass {

    private boolean result = false;

    public boolean getResult() {
    return result;
    }

    public void setResult(boolean setResult) {
    this.result = setResult;
    }
}
```

**Expected Scenario:** When a piece of code is edited and saved in a method where the debug pointer is currently present then the debug pointer should move to first line of the method where the debug pointer is currently present.

**Actual Scenario:** When a piece of code is edited and saved in a method where the debug pointer is currently present then the debug pointer moves to first line of source method instead of moving to first line of method where the debug pointer is currently present.

Comment: For me it works as expected, Eclipse 4.6

Comment: @ChrisH Edited the code and made it short! Updated the code above.

Comment: @Zefick try the updated code!

Answer (score 2):

Changing the code during debugging will make that method re-execute form the beginning because it has to reset the local variables in that method.
For more details on how it work or how to use debug option properly refer to below link..
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/

> If you are running Java Virtual Machine (JVM) V1.4 or higher, Eclipse
>   supports a feature called Hotswap Bug Fixing (not available in JVM
>   V1.3 or lower). It allows the changing of source code during a
>   debugger session, which is better than exiting the application,
>   changing the code, recompiling, then starting another debugging
>   session. To use this function, simply change the code in the editor
>   and resume debugging

One more thing: While debugging, just change any code and save it, eclipse will automatically transfer the modified code to the target VM.
Note that you can't make structural changes to the code, like adding new methods, changing method signature or adding new fields. But you can change the code within a method.